# Not getting ord() of hexadecimal values when reading from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose `a = '\x00\x01\x02'`

Now when I use `ord()` by looping through `a`, I get the output I want.

**Program:**

```
for i in a:
    ord(i)
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
2
```

But now when I do the same by reading from a file, I keep getting TypeError.

This is what I did- I created a file named *abc.txt*. Inside *abc.txt* there is the same string as `a`which is `'\x00\x01\x02'`.

This is the program I wrote for going through the contents of the file:

```
file = open('abc.txt', 'r')

for i in file:
    ord(i)

file.close()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 15 found
```

Where am I going wrong? It works perfectly fine when I'm assigning the string to a variable but I keep getting error when I'm performing the same operation while reading from a file.

**EDIT**

I tried Morgan Thrapp's solution and it worked. But now I have another problem. When I'm looping through `a`, I get the ord() of the hexadecimal values given in the string. But when I'm going by Morgan's method, I get the ord() of single characters in the string. The program doesn't see it as hexadecimal values in the string while looping.
I also changed the title so that it is more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: When you iterate over a file, you read it in line by line not character by character.

Comment: And "length 15" indicates you probably just copy/pasted the escaped string, not actually inserted the 3 characters into the file

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one. If you have a new question, create a new question. Like you were told in the comments on my answer, you're not actually putting those bytes in the file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're iterating over the file line by line, but the string character by character.

The easiest way is to either use a second nested loop, or `map`.

```
with open('abc.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
         for character in line:
             print(ord(character))
```

Comment: Or `for character in input_file.read():`, if the file is not too large.

Comment: This time it worked but I'm not getting the same output as what I'd get if I assigned the string to the variable.
When I'm looping though `a`, I get the ord() of the hexadecimal values given in the string. But when I'm going by your method, I get the ord() of single characters. It doesn't even see it as hexadecimal values.

Comment: That is correct. You have to put the actual bytes in the file, text files don't have a concept of encoded bytes. So, for your example, you'd need to paste `` into your file.

Comment: @Parthib: You are writing the escape characters, but they are just Python's representation of the unprintable characters.  You should write the characters to the file from Python, not manually.